# Showing SweetAlert for custom session?

Tags: php, sweetalert

is it possible to show sweet alert pop-up to desired session?

This is how i set session for every user:

```
  $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

And i have no idea how should i complete the next step, any thoughts ?
What I'm trying to achieve is once postbacks sends data and updates points for user i want to show him a sweet alert.

sid equals to username

```
$getusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_GET['sid']); 
$query = "UPDATE users SET points = points + '$okpayout' WHERE username='$getusername' ";
mysqli_query($db, $query);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for data in session and then based on that show the sweetalert in the view:

```
<?php
    $session_data = $_SESSION['field'] ?? null; // With php >= 7
    $session_data = isset($_SESSION['field']) ? $_SESSION['field'] : null; // With php < 7

   if ($session_data && $session_data == "value") {
       echo '
        <script>  swal("Done!"); </script>
      ';
   }
?>
```